# Exchange 2007 All Rooms address list issue

Tags: exchange-2007

I am currently looking at setting up resource mailboxes for our meeting rooms.  Have a strange issue: when booking the meeting room using the scheduling assistant, I add the room to the meeting request, choose the “All Rooms” address list and it does not show the correct columns.  I would expect to see capacity and descriptions, but it shows the same columns as every other address list.

Does anyone know how to add these columns back or what may have happened to stop them showing?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: two questions: 1) which Outlook client (and does it show up fine in OWA?) 2) Is the address book the default Rooms book or did you create a custom one?

Comment: 1)Outlook 2007 - and it displays the same way in OWA.  2)As far as I know it is the default Room book, but as I inherited the mail servers I am starting to think it must have been recreated.  If this is the case, do you know of a way to re-instate the default one?

Comment: If it displays without capacity in OWA, it is probably a custom list.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the default back.  Creating a custom list won't include capacity as you have seen.

Comment: Thanks TheCleaner - you pointed me in the right direction. For anyone else who has this issue, here is what i needed to do to resolve it:

Comment: See below answer

Comment: ah...yeah I saw that in a blog but figured all that would do is let the config know to use your custom list.  I didn't realize it would start to show capacity as well.  Good job!

Comment: Thought it was worth a shot when I noticed our resource address list was showing in deleted objects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that All Rooms had indead been deleted and recreated.  To reinstate properly had to:

•Run ADSIEdit, connect to well known naming Configuration
•Go to Configuration->Services->Microsoft Exchange->Your org->Address Lists Container->All Address Lists
•Right Click properties CN=All Rooms, Select the value Distinguished Name and click Edit, copy
•Once you have the DN of your address list, right click CN=Your Org and go to properties, select the msExchResourceAddressLists attribute and click the edit button. 
•Copy the contents and paste to text file to backup.
•Remove the old entry and paste the DN of the All Rooms address list.